Get NEAR blockchain transactions
I try to get all transactions of an account from NEAR blockchain. Apparently, nearblocks.io provides an API to retrieve them from, since they index the NEAR blockchain (as I understood). However, when calling their API with their provided endpoint
https://api.nearblocks.io/v1/account/{{address}}/txns

they return a list of transactions, but not including the important details e.g. the amount of NEAR that really was used/transferred or the delivered smart contract properties (as they are also stated in the nearblocks explorer). Sometimes, the log contains some information, but I do not really want to parse log messages.
When I call
https://api.nearblocks.io/v1/account/{{address}}/txns

I get an answer like this:
[{
      "receipt_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "predecessor_account_id": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "receiver_account_id": "wrap.near",
      "transaction_hash": "XXXXXXXX",
      "included_in_block_hash": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
      "block_timestamp": "XXXXXXXX",
      "block": {
        "block_height": XXXXXXXX
      },
      "actions": [
        {
          "action": "FUNCTION_CALL",
          "method": "near_withdraw"
        }
      ],
      "actions_agg": {
        "deposit": 1
      },
      "outcomes": {
        "status": true
      },
      "outcomes_agg": {
        "transaction_fee": 613612255871800000000
      },
      "logs": [
        "Withdraw 439868187227909566414206558 NEAR from XXXXX"
      ]
    }, {...}
]

The information I need is written in the logs! However, the logs are not standardized and I need the information in one of the fields above.
Is there another way to get my transactions with all relevant data? Or is there another API? The contact form of nearblocks is broken, so I cannot ask them directly.
Thanks a lot for support

I guess the only solution is to use the tx hashes retrieved from call above and call the rpc-api of near blockchain directly using https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org/ with following json-content:
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": "dontcare",
"method": "EXPERIMENTAL_tx_status",
"params": {
"tx_hash": "TRANSACTION_HASH_FROM_ENTRY_ABOVE",
"sender_account_id": "XXX.near",
"wait_until": "EXECUTED"
}
}
But executing really a REST call for each entry in the list? Is there not a better solution?

The amount of Near coins transferred is already included in the API (actions_agg.deposit). But you are referring to the wNEAR token here. They have another API that provides txn details including token transfers
https://api.nearblocks.io/v1/txns/6sE2s66MBpYU8oEr555y7Zwfp3ru3DecfjCfXZgJPAka


{
  "txns": [
    {
      "transaction_hash": "6sE2s66MBpYU8oEr555y7Zwfp3ru3DecfjCfXZgJPAka",
      ...,
      "receipts": [
        {
          "fts": [
            {
              "event_index": 1.712306366424077e+34,
              "affected_account_id": "phemyade.tg",
              "involved_account_id": null,
              "delta_amount": -3.129931260242137e+23,
              "cause": "BURN",
              "block_timestamp": 1712306366424077000,
              "ft_meta": {
                "contract": "wrap.near",
                "name": "Wrapped NEAR fungible token",
                "symbol": "wNEAR",
                "icon": null,
                "decimals": 24
              }
            }
          ],
          "nfts": []
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Thanks for the answer! You are right by saying, I am referring to a transaction involving the wNEAR token. The overall transaction is actually a withdrawal process/exchange from wNEAR to NEAR.
However, my token transactions can be found using the API /account/{{address}}/ft-txns, the corresponding account transactions using the address I wrote (v1/account/{{address}}/txns) or directly using the endpoint you mentioned /v1/txns/{{hash}}. All of information can be combined to know the amount of wrapped NEAR, that were exchanged. I am searching the amount of NEAR that is involved (not wrapped)!

The actions_agg.deposit parameter of this account transaction is set to 1 (yoctoNEAR), so it does not reflect the amount of NEAR that reached my account. However, when calling the rpc-endpoint from near mainnet directly (using the tx hash from nearblocks), I receive all the necessary receipts, also including the (non-wrapped) NEAR coin amount being involved. I was just curious if also nearblocks provides such an endpoint directly to retrieve the list of accounts including this information, so I do not have to call hundreds of times the rpc-API on mainnet for each transaction.

Oh ok, for that I think you have to call rpc. I dont think they have a similar api

It does sound like you need a specific indexer for your needs. Try using NEAR Lake Framework or QueryAPI for this purpose.

Thanks a lot for the hint. I read about the indexers, nevertheless avoided to familiarize myself into it, up to now. Maybe I should put some effort in it, since it sounds powerful and useful.
However, I thought the Nearblocks API with costs up to hundreds of Euro per month should provide some simple information as the deposited NEAR amount within transactions...just to avoid to implement complex logic otherwise.
